# Center vertically in UILabel with autoshrink

Tags: ios, uilabel

This is a little different from all the other "How do I center the text in a `UILabel`" questions here...

I have a `UILabel` with some text in it, I want to center the text vertically in the `UILabel`. What's the big deal, right? That's the default. The problem comes because my text is dynamic and I have autoshrink turn on. As the text grows larger, the font size shrinks. You get this behavior.

[image]

Notice that the font baseline has not moved, I want it to move so the numbers are centered vertically in the `UILabel's` frame.

Easy, right? I just remember the frame's original center in `viewDidLoad`

```
    self.workoutTimeCenter = _workoutTimeLabel.center;
```

and then I call `sizeToFit` after I change the the text, right?

```
    [_workoutTimeLabel sizeToFit];
    _workoutTimeLabel.center = _workoutTimeCenter;
```

Well, `sizeToFit` did, I guess, exactly what it was supposed to do, resize the frame so the text fits without shrinking!

[image]

How can I vertically center the text in a `UILabel` while respecting baselines and autoshrink? (Note, an **iOS5** and later solution is fine and I can even deal with an **iOS6** and later solution.)

Comment: you create label programmatically or on the xib file.

Comment: I've built the label in the xib

Comment: what about embedding your UILabel in a bigger UIView, and then center the UILabel in the UIView simpy using label.center = fatherView.center; ?

Comment: I'm not following that, the baseline still wouldn't be centered.

Comment: @PaulCezanne Can you explain a bit more ? your requirement is Something like my answer or else ? I'm confused with baseline and fontsize.

Comment: @TheTiger, hmmm, your answers looks pretty good. I probably can't test it today, I'm traveling, but I'll look at it soon. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulCezanne - Ok .. :) Happy Journey

Answer (score 116, accepted):

In my experience you can just set the `-[UILabel baselineAdjustment]` property to `UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters` to achieve the effect you're describing.

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/baselineAdjustment):

> ### baselineAdjustment
>
> Controls how text baselines are adjusted when text
>   needs to shrink to fit in the label.
>
> ```
> @property(nonatomic) UIBaselineAdjustment baselineAdjustment
> ```
>
> #### Discussion
>
> If the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property is set to `YES`,
>   this property controls the behavior of the text baselines in
>   situations where adjustment of the font size is required. The default
>   value of this property is `UIBaselineAdjustment`**`AlignBaselines`**. This
>   property is effective only when the `numberOfLines` property is set to
>   `1`.

and

> `UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters`
>   Adjust text based relative to the center of its bounding box.

**EDIT: adding a full view-controller that demonstrates this:**

```
@interface TSViewController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation TSViewController

- (void) addLabelWithFrame: (CGRect) f baselineAdjustment: (UIBaselineAdjustment) bla
{
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: f];
    label.baselineAdjustment = bla;
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Courier" size: 200];
    label.text = @"00";
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview: label];

    UIView* centerline = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(f.origin.x, f.origin.y+(f.size.height/2.0), f.size.width, 1)];
    centerline.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview: centerline];

    UITapGestureRecognizer* tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(onTap:)];
    [label addGestureRecognizer: tgr];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addLabelWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)
         baselineAdjustment: UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters];

    [self addLabelWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 220, 320, 200)
         baselineAdjustment: UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines];
}

- (void) onTap: (UITapGestureRecognizer*) tgr
{
    UILabel* label = (UILabel*)tgr.view;
    NSString* t = [label.text stringByAppendingString: @":00"];
    label.text = t;
}

@end
```

Comment: +1 This is correct way. Many answers trying to calculate the frame manually, but it's this simple. And it's available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Comment: It's working in my test app.  Can you create a simple test case to sleuth it out?  Or I could post mine.

Comment: I can send you the whole source code if you want, it is pretty small, just an exercise time. oblique at alum dot mit dot edu

Comment: well, I really don't want your source.  but I'll update my answer with my test-case and you can go from there.

Comment: Hmmm, it looks awfully similar to my code, the only difference in mine is that my view controller is contained in another view controller, but I have a hard time believing that that matters.

Comment: ok, I'll mark this correct since I'm sure you did the heavy lifting, but your missing one more part. My UILabels came from InterfaceBuilder which had "Tighten Letter Spacing" turn ON. Turning that off, with the above code, does the trick. If you could modify your answer that would be awesome. And thanks for sticking with me!

Comment: it seems that using adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth breaks baselineAdjustment.  I don't see this documented anywhere; probably merits filing a radar bug with Apple.  I'll do that.

Comment: @TomSwift I'd upvote this answer 10000 times if I could. Thanks!

Comment: also, make sure lineBreakMode is not "Word Wrap"

Answer (score 14):

when working in IB, be sure to set align baselines to center

[image]

**Note: line break CANNOT be word wrap for this to work, so it will NOT work multiline (good to set the line break to Truncate tail)**

Comment: the Most elegant solution!

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)fitVerticallyToLabel:(UILabel *)lbl
{
    CGFloat fontSize = lbl.frame.size.width / lbl.text.length;
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:fontSize]];

    CGRect rect = lbl.frame;
    rect.origin.y += rect.size.height - fontSize;
    rect.size.height = fontSize;
    [lbl setFrame:rect];
}
```

**How to Use: Call this method after setting the text to your label.**

```
    label.text = @"text";
    [self fitVerticallyToLabel:label];
```

[image][image]

**Note: I ahev taken UILabel from xib. You can take it programmatically too in that case you will have to set its text alignment NSTextAlignMentCenter**

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement this logic:

```
-(void)adjustLabel1Text1:(NSString *)text1 
{
    UILabel *lbl_first = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];



    text1 = [text1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


    float hedingLblHeight = [self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:text1 : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12] :118 :UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    lbl_first.text=text1;


    [lbl_first setFrame:CGRectMake(lbl_first.frame.origin.x, lbl_first.frame.origin.y, 118, hedingLblHeight)];
    lbl_first.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    lbl_first.numberOfLines = 0;
    [lbl_first sizeToFit];




//////////Adjust the lable or any UIControl below this label accordingly.

    float endResultHeight=[self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:text2 : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15] :299 :UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    if(hedingLblHeight>secondImgTitleHeight)
    {
    [lbl_endResult setFrame:CGRectMake(lbl_endResult.frame.origin.x, lbl_first.frame.origin.y+lbl_first.frame.size.height+5, 299, endResultHeight)];
    }
    else
    {
        [lbl_endResult setFrame:CGRectMake(lbl_endResult.frame.origin.x, lbl_first.frame.origin.y+lbl_first.frame.size.height+5, 299, endResultHeight)];

    }

    lbl_endResult.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    lbl_endResult.numberOfLines = 0;
    [lbl_endResult sizeToFit];



}

-(float) calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString*)text : (UIFont*) withFont:(float)width :(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
{

    CGSize suggestedSize = [text sizeWithFont:withFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];

    return suggestedSize.height;
}
```

It has helped me a lot.Hope it works for you.

Answer (score -5):

Try

```
yourLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Comment: Use 'NSTextAlignmentCenter' for targeting iOS6!

Comment: This isn't what he was asking.

Comment: centers horizontally not vertically